Shell Eco Marathon Hydrogen Prototype Class
I am a part of a team developing propulsion system for the shell Eco Marathon Hydrogen Prototype class. I  wat to size the PEM fuel cell correctly. Can anyone provide some resources or detailed procedures for it? I am using a 300-watt BLDC hub motor.

Start with "what is the load" and think peak, and duration.
